# OLD ESXi Host needs to be upgraded however SSH is not working after being turned on

Tags: vmware-esxi

So I've been asked to look at an ESXi 5.5 host which needs upgrades/updates big time.

It is a Dell server...I've enabled SSH however the same root/password combination I can log into the GUI with doesn't seem to work with the SSH client (Putty)..I've also tried OSX terminal to SSH in with no luck..

"Permission denied, please try again."
is the message I get when trying to log in..

I need to get in so I can upload patches and run them to upgrade the host...at least to the newest 5.5 for now..

Thanks

EDIT I have also added another account and enabled shell access and get the same result...

Comment: Is the SSH port open on the firewall?

Comment: ESXi 5.5 has been end of life since 2018. Upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider did you not read the comment above that is the goal..

Comment: @Davidw yes because I would not have been able to get to the prompt to do the SSH login or password....

Comment: Then why bother with updates? Just install the newer version.

Comment: According to the [upgrade path](https://interopmatrix.vmware.com/Upgrade) you can Upgrade 5.5 directly to 6.5 and then 6.5 to 7.0

Comment: Have you checked the server hardware against the VMware HCL for the version you want to move to?

Comment: @Chopper3 all set there...but again without being able to SSH into the machine it is difficult to do much of anything..

Comment: You can't upgrade to a newer major version via SSH anyway. Create an installation media from the next version in the upgrade path, boot from it, install it and choose to keep your VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes root user got blocked for try many times without luck.Check that ssh service is running on esxi and that esxi firewall is not blocking incomming connections. If you need to upgrade asap, choose another aproach.

Create or downlod dell custom iso and use Server IPMI. If you can't use virtual cd-rom, you should create a booteable pendrive to upgrade your server. **Remember to check Vmware HCL, vmware interoperability matrix and upgrade path.**